# async.waterfall callback is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I have done this before but I don't know what's wrong. The callback to the second function in async waterfall is undefined. My code is as follows.

```
async.waterfall([
                function(callback){

                     var body = "some json string"
                     var b = JSON.parse(body);
                     return callback(null, b);
                }
                , function(data, callback){
                    mongodb.somecollection({somequery}, function(err, res){
                    if(!err){
                    var returnObj = {
                        success:true, 
                        data:{
                            access_token: "user token", 
                            end_date: "some date"
                        }, 
                        msg: "some string",
                        ref_code: "user_id"
                    };
                        callback(null, returnObj);
                   }
                    else{
                        callback(err);
                    }
                    });
                }
            ], function(err, result){

                if(!err){
                    return reply(result).type('application/json').code(200)
                }
                else{
                    err.trace = err.stack;
                    logger.log('error', err);
                    return reply(helper.responseHelper.Error('Something went wrong. Try again.')).type('application/json').code(200);
                }
        });
```

I am getting the following error where the second callback is called inside the mongo callback.

> TypeError: Uncaught error: undefined is not a function

Can anybody please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Below is the stacktrace.

```
Debug: internal, implementation, error
TypeError: Uncaught error: undefined is not a function
at /Users/audiocompass/Sites/api/controllers/users.js:776:12
at /Users/audiocompass/Sites/api/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/collection/core.js:588:7
at /Users/audiocompass/Sites/api/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1195:7
at bound (domain.js:254:14)
at runBound (domain.js:267:12)
at /Users/audiocompass/Sites/api/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1903:9
at bound (domain.js:254:14)
at runBound (domain.js:267:12)
at Server.Base._callHandler (/Users/audiocompass/Sites/api/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:453:41)
at /Users/audiocompass/Sites/api/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:487:18
```

Comment: Can you post the whole stacktrace here? Also what are you getting in the data parameter.

Comment: I'll admit it: I'm stumped. Looks correct to me.

Comment: The callback is probably passed as the first argument, can you check that? Also, what's the real value of 'b' in the first function?

Comment: I have added the stacktrace. The data passed is an json of the users facebook profile data same as "b" after parsing the facebook response i.e. {
  "id": "my facebook id",
  "name": "Gaurav",
  "email": "my email"
}. @CViejo: what do you mean?

Comment: looks great for me ! @gaurav are you still with trouble ? hapi is a good choice ! ;) let me know if you still have trouble.

Comment: i think replacing callback(null, returnObj) with callback() will solve the problem, this is an old post... but i hope it will be useful to someone.